# Is there a way to disable the save states on PPSSPP menu?

Tags: emulation, psp

I want to hide or disable the save states on the PPSSPP pause menu since I don't use it so I'd rather have the interface clean of it. I've checked out every section in the settings and can't seem to find it. That or I'm just blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can tell from a quick look at the [code for the pause screen](https://github.com/hrydgard/ppsspp/blob/master/UI/PauseScreen.cpp), specifically the GamePauseScreen::CreateViews() function, it doesn't seem like there's a conditional check that would remove the save states feature.

That said, if you're feeling adventurous, you could try removing the entry from the pause screen and recompile.  That may be more trouble than you're willing to go through, though :)

Comment: Alright thanks! I have to consider first if I'm willing to go through setting up the source and compiling